# Create a node Programmatically having Composed Field

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have a content type having composed filed (used [Composed Field](https://drupal.org/project/composed_field) module for this).

How can I create a node programmatically with composed field values?

Comment: need to know if you have problem in mapping composed field value while saving a node programmatically or you need to know how to save a node programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Consider with this example
you created a field as contact with two subfields as mobile(textfield) and home(textfield).

so while creating the node pro grammatically you just have to assign the array of your input to the field,something like below

```
$contact = array("mobile"=>"1234565","home"=>"789");
$node->field_contact[$node->language][0]['composed'] = $contact;
```

I have not shared the node_save() as you have mentioned you are able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

In theory the same principle should be applied.
Can you try using "Devel" module, to see the structure of the "composed" node
and then try to copy (structure) in the new node.

For example, Drupal Commons has "organic group" reference field. "og_ref".
you can try..

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->composed_field (copy structure from Devel).
```

Regards

Regards.